# Why ReactJs htmlFor not hidding input field

Tags: html, reactjs

that react htmlFor isn't hidding input field with label. Maybe someone could tell me, what I am doing wrong?

My code:

```
<input name="tes" id="tes" type="file" className="inputfile" />
             <label htmlFor="tes">
                 <span>Upload</span>
             </label>
```

Comment: In which part of that code you're trying to hide something?

Comment: Why would htmlFor hide anything? What is it you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

You told me in comments, you want to hide the `input` tag.
Just add the attribute `style="display:none"` to your input tag.

Like this:

```
 <input name="tes" id="tes" type="file" className="inputfile" style="display:none"/>
```

Comment: I am using it in react. It is htmlFor there.

Comment: Yes. But it returns input field and label. I want to return only label.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Delete <input name="tes" id="tes" type="file" className="inputfile" /> from your code. Then it isn't shown.

Comment: If you only want to hide it, look at my edited answer.

Comment: I am glad that I could help :)